# How to print a string without quotes?

Tags: rust

I want to display the players' name and score, but I cannot figure out how to print the name without the quotes:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    score: i32,
    turn_count: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let players: Vec<Player> = ...;
    for player in players {
        println!("{:X?} {:?}", player.name, player.score);
    }
}
```

```
"STUART" 23
"KEVIN" 0
"BOB" 5
```

Comment: What is `pvec` and `p_num`?

Comment: Use `{}` instead of `{:?}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're formatting with `?` which uses the [`std::fmt::Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait instead of `Display`. The debug formatter prints strings with quotation marks while the normal formatter does not.

```rust
let cat = "Cat";
println!("{:?}", cat);
println!("{}", cat);
```

```
"Cat"
Cat
```

Check out the [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) documentation and [formatted print tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print.html) for more details.

Comment: even more confusing, a debugger will show you the quotes, so it looks like you actually have a  string in quotes